# ValueError: x and y must be the same size when ploting predicted values

Tags: python, matplotlib, linear-regression

I am trying to plot my predicted values against my independent variable

if they were the same shape to be able to fit into model why would not they be the same size? yes they are not the same since X has multiple attributes as Y is one independent variable but still, I do not understand how to plot them

Code:

```
# generate random data-set
np.random.seed(0)
x = df1
y = subjects["heart_rate"]

#x= x.values.reshape(-1, 1)
#y= y.values.reshape(-1, 1)

#x.shape[0] != y.shape[0]
# sckit-learn implementation

# Model initialization
regression_model = LinearRegression()
# Fit the data(train the model)
regression_model.fit(x, y)
# Predict
y_predicted = regression_model.predict(x)

# model evaluation
rmse = mean_squared_error(y, y_predicted)
r2 = r2_score(y, y_predicted)

# printing values
print('Slope:' ,regression_model.coef_)
print('Intercept:', regression_model.intercept_)
print('Root mean squared error: ', rmse)
print('R2 score: ', r2)

# plotting values

# data points

plt.scatter(x, y, s=10)
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')

# predicted values
plt.plot(x, y_predicted, color='r')
plt.show()
```

Error:

```
Slope: [-5.37064533 -0.50880666 -0.09348247 -1.33726289  0.18639004  1.42313131
 -0.2752906   0.26580939 -0.17365683 -0.13841734]
Intercept: 274.5378817549546
Root mean squared error:  498.2107065101733
R2 score:  0.31625521784258237
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-179-a4bdd40003d3> in <module>()
     31 # data points
     32 
---> 33 plt.scatter(x, y, s=10)
     34 plt.xlabel('x')
     35 plt.ylabel('y')

c:\python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py in scatter(x, y, s, c, marker, cmap, norm, vmin, vmax, alpha, linewidths, verts, edgecolors, hold, data, **kwargs)
   3473                          vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax, alpha=alpha,
   3474                          linewidths=linewidths, verts=verts,
-> 3475                          edgecolors=edgecolors, data=data, **kwargs)
   3476     finally:
   3477         ax._hold = washold

c:\python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py in inner(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1865                         "the Matplotlib list!)" % (label_namer, func.__name__),
   1866                         RuntimeWarning, stacklevel=2)
-> 1867             return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1868 
   1869         inner.__doc__ = _add_data_doc(inner.__doc__,

c:\python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py in scatter(self, x, y, s, c, marker, cmap, norm, vmin, vmax, alpha, linewidths, verts, edgecolors, **kwargs)
   4255         y = np.ma.ravel(y)
   4256         if x.size != y.size:
-> 4257             raise ValueError("x and y must be the same size")
   4258 
   4259         if s is None:

ValueError: x and y must be the same size
```

X:

```
IMU_hand_temp   hand_acceleration_16_1  hand_acceleration_16_2  hand_acceleration_16_3  hand_gyroscope_rad_7    hand_gyroscope_rad_8    hand_gyroscope_rad_9    hand_magnetometer_μT_10 hand_magnetometer_μT_11 hand_magnetometer_μT_12
0   30.375  2.21530 8.27915 5.58753 -0.004750   0.037579    -0.011145   8.93200 -67.9326    -19.9755
1   30.375  2.29196 7.67288 5.74467 -0.171710   0.025479    -0.009538   9.58300 -67.9584    -20.9091
2   30.375  2.29090 7.14240 5.82342 -0.238241   0.011214    0.000831    9.05516 -67.4017    -19.5083
3   30.375  2.21800 7.14365 5.89930 -0.192912   0.019053    0.013374    9.92698 -67.4387    -20.5602
4   30.375  2.30106 7.25857 6.09259 -0.069961   -0.018328   0.004582    9.15626 -67.1825    -20.0857
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
1942867 25.125  4.99466 6.01881 5.59830 -0.289166   -0.110170   0.238570    -4.79353    -18.1271    -48.2695
1942868 25.125  5.02764 5.90369 5.48372 -0.275411   -0.128358   0.267409    -4.54101    -18.0169    -48.9268
1942869 25.125  5.06409 5.71370 5.48491 -0.289885   -0.126548   0.281483    -4.17401    -17.9121    -48.4032
1942870 25.125  5.13914 5.63724 5.48629 -0.234417   -0.101485   0.275497    -4.66091    -18.2588    -49.0563
1942871 25.125  5.00812 5.40645 5.02326 -0.260924   -0.093849   0.266205    -5.05008    -17.6169    -48.1408
```

y:

```
0          100.0
1          100.0
2          100.0
3          100.0
4          100.0
           ...  
1942867    162.0
1942868    162.0
1942869    162.0
1942870    162.0
1942871    162.0
Name: heart_rate, Length: 1942872, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to generate a scatter plot of the DataFrame `x` (a 1942871 X N object) against the Series `y`. The code fails because `x` has more elements in total than `y`.

```py
print('size of x = {0}'.format(x.size))
print('size of y = {0}'.format(y.size))
assert x.size == y.size
```

The sizes are not equal, hence the code fails.

If you must have a scatter plot of `x` against `y`, do so on a column-by-column basis

```py
for col in x.columns:
   plt.scatter(x[col], y, s=10)
```

Comment: I have just done that and it returns KeyError: 'IMU_hand_temp' this is the name of the first columns in x why does it count the names of the columns?

Comment: @Zaid I believe it should be `plt.scatter(x[col], y, s=10)`